# Help to understand the Monty Hall problem formally

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, monty-hall

The concept of the problem is well known. So, in short for not to waste your time guys:

- $A$ - behind the door #1 there's a car
- $B$ - Monty opens the door #3
- $C$ - behind the door #2 there's a car

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A)P(A)\ +\ P(B|C)P(C)} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{2}$

Comments:
I assume that the probability that behind a door there's a car to equal $\frac{1}{3}$ because there's 3 possible arrangements. Also I assume that the events "Car Behind Door #N"  make a partition of the sample space, that's how I derived the denominator.

Could you help me to understand where the flaw in my formulation. I think about it 10 hours and have not got further than this... Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with $P(A \mid B)=\frac12$ if you assume that the player initially selects a door at random, and then Monty chooses a non-selected non-car door at random.  Indeed, by symmetry this is obvious.  What you are missing is that the player knows which door was selected initially and can use that information.  Let $D$ be the event that door #1 was the original section and find $P(A \mid B,D) =\frac13$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flaw is in the fact that Monthy knows what's behind the doors and he MUST choose a door that doesn't end the game directly. So the probability of opening door $3$ given the car is behind door $2$ is 100%; because he can't open door $1$ and $2$.

So

$$P(B|C) =1 $$i.e.$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\ +\ 1\cdot\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Hm, well, I understand what you're trying to say and already thought about it. But when I say $P(B|C)$ I have no knowledge about anything happened before, so the answer is obviously $\frac{1}{2}$ because giving the car is behind the door #2 the he could open either the door #3 or #1

Comment: but he will never open door 1, because then he would reveal directly your win or loss and the game would end

Comment: I mean, you can say it's $P(B|C) = 1$ only if you know, that the original choice was the door #1, i.e. $P(B|C \cap D) = 1$ ($D$ for "I have picked the door #1")

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I understand what you mean. Please keep in mind that formally $P(B|C) \ne P(B|C \cap D)$ where $D$ for "I have picked the door #1".

Comment: read my previous comment: he cannot open door 1, because after he opens a door: he has to ask the question: will you switch or not? And that's not possible if he opens door 1, so the probability is always $1$ on opening door 3, given door 2 has the car. Try playing it and you'll see.

Comment: Finally, thank you so much for helping me out. Now I see, I have just ruined the rules of the game making partition with only the condition "the car behind the door #N"! All my probabilities should have the condition "the door #1 is picked". You have opened my eyes, I did not use all relevant information in my equations.. What a pity..

Answer (score 1):

The famous counterintuitive result comes from the host deliberately revealing a goat behind an unselected door, so $P(B|C)=\color{limegreen}{1}$. So the result is$$\frac{\frac12\cdot\frac13}{\frac12\cdot\frac13+\color{limegreen}{1}\cdot\frac13}=\frac13.$$Edit: as @Henry notes, this is based on labelling the first door selected as door 1.

Comment: You seem to have assumed that the door initially selected was #1.  If so, it might be worth saying so